# using method inside asyntask in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

i have created one simple login application  which takes user name and password from sqlserver..it works fine...

i want during login process one progeress bar should be displayed using asyntask...
but i am unaware to use parameters in asyntask...if some one plzz tell me how to put my method in doInbackground of asyntask  and what param should i use....

my code is;.....

```
public void save(){
    initilize();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String mylog=id.getText().toString();
    String mypass=pass.getText().toString();
    try{
    Statement statement=connect.createStatement();
    rs=statement.executeQuery("LOGIN '"+mylog+"', '"+mypass+"'");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(mylog.equals("")||mypass.equals("")){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "empty fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else
        try {
            if(rs.next()){

                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Act2.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else if(rs.next()==false){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "incorrect login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                id.setText("");
                pass.setText("");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

if it is possible that same method save() be kept inside doInbackground() of  asyntask...

Answer (score 0):

making a fast refactorization (note that this as it stand it's really bad practice and coding, you MUST refactor this code to be more maintanable and to avoid duplication):

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<> {
```

private Activity activity;
     boolean result;
     private String myLog;
     private String myPass;
     private Connection connect;

```
public MyAsyncTask(Activity activity, Connection connect) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.connect = connect;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    //show your progress dialog
}

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

    ResultSet rs = null;
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initilize();
                mylog=id.getText().toString();
                mypass=pass.getText().toString();
            }
        });

        try{
            Statement statement=connect.createStatement();
            rs=statement.executeQuery("LOGIN '"+mylog+"', '"+mypass+"'");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(mylog.equals("")||mypass.equals("")){
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "empty fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


        } else
            try {
                if(rs.next()){
                result = true;

                }
                else if(rs.next()==false){

                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "incorrect login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            id.setText("");
                            pass.setText("");
                        }
                    });

                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
    //hide your progress dialog
    if(result == Boolean.TRUE){
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i=new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(),Act2.class);
                activity.startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

then in your Activity you do this:

```
MyAsyncTask a = new MyAsyncTask(this, connect); //im guessing "connect" is your Connection object
a.execute();
```

As i said i made this fast refactoring for the code to work but best practice and good implementation is not in consideration here.

Comment: what parameter should i pass to asyntask<?,?,?>

Comment: the code as stand you don't need to pass parameters to AsyncTask<?,?,?> just pass the parameters on the Constructor, im guessing those are the parameters you need to pass (the activity for access the UI thread and the Connection object)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you could use a timer, to check if your 
login is ready. As long as it is not, you Show your progress Bar. If its ready, you can close the Bar and start a new activity or anything. timers run can run on u UI thread. 
regards :)